# What does createdCollectionAutomatically mean?

Tags: mongodb

When I create an index on a collection, one of the properties of the result document is `createCollectionAutomatically:false`.

```
db.myCollection.createIndex({"address":1})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 3,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

What does it mean and when is this true?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createIndexes/#output

> The `createdCollectionAutomatically` indicates if the operation
>     created a collection. If a collection does not exist, MongoDB
>     creates the collection as part of the indexing
>     operation.

So when I run `db.myCollection.createIndex({"address":1})` and `myCollection` does not exists, the result is

```
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: The referred link is not existing any more. `404`. I am changing the link to right reference in mongoDB documentation.